# simple and idiomatic way for Visual Studio applications to invoke without PATH modifications

Tags: visual-studio, inno-setup

What is the simple and idiomatic way for Visual Studio applications to invoke each other in the Visual Studio development directory tree and also in the deployed situation? (Assume that Inno Setup is the installer.)

Currently, I define a value in the .NET configuration file element `"appSettings"` to specify where an invocable `MyApp.exe` file resides in a development directory tree. In `"appSettings"` I will provide the string `“..\..\..\projectName\bin\DebugOrRelease\MyApp.exe”` and have the program use `#if DEBUG` to set a compile-time constant boolean. The compile-time constant boolean is used to convert the `“DebugOrRelease”` token into either `“Debug”` or `“Release”`. Using the converted token, the file will be checked for existence. If the file does not exist, the "invoker" program infers that we are not in a development situation but rather the deployed situation, so the target becomes `“.\MyApp.exe”`. Obviously, I tell Inno Setup to drop all the executable files into the same folder, which conveniently is the default behaviour when you use the Inno Setup wizard to create the Inno Setup Script.

I've tried to avoid using the PATH environment variable for perhaps not completely rational reasons but I do have distant memories of editing paths for other peoples' commercial applications in the default variable pitch sans-serif font where “1” looks like “l” and both look like the slow-blinking cursor and the whole PATH string is about 10 times wider than the text box and keyboard auto-repeat is both too fast and too delayed. In other words, I hate editing the PATH and the default font and keyboard parameters and cursor blink rate and text box seem ill-suited for this purpose. Perhaps an Inno Setup compilation can do automatic PATH editing but regardless I also don't like imposing anything on the environment. It's a form of pollution. Furthermore, a good solution should work on both the development machine and the deployment machine. While, I fully expect some applications that I want to deploy require PATH additions I'm more reluctant to add to PATH for a development machine. Everything on a development machine is transient and editing PATH for a transient need is annoying. I will have to remember to remove it from PATH if development proceeds in a different direction. Lastly, I think Inno Setup PATH editing is supported by some sort of add-in (http://legroom.net/software/modpath) and I prefer solutions that do not involve additional tools.

Given my aversion to modifying PATH, what I have devised and described here is my general solution for Visual Studio solutions that deploy with Inno Setup. While it does not involve a large amount of code, it does strike me as awkward and so my question is, how would this be done more simply and idiomatically?

Comment: Using PATH is generally a very drastic mistake.  Anything else is better, not limited to simply using a single well-known directory for all executable files.  The simple solution.  Second-best is probably the [App Paths registry key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So perhaps a post-build procedure copies from the development directory tree to the well-known place. I didn't know about post-build procedures at the time I devised this scheme.